# In Spark can two executor access the same object in disk if both are in the same host?

Tags: apache-spark

```
/**
   * Get the remote block and transform it to the provided data type.
   *
   * If the block is persisted to the disk and stored at an executor running on the same host then
   * first it is tried to be accessed using the local directories of the other executor directly.
   * If the file is successfully identified then tried to be transformed by the provided
   * transformation function which expected to open the file. If there is any exception during this
   * transformation then block access falls back to fetching it from the remote executor via the
   * network.
   *
```

In [getRemoteBlock](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManager.scala#L1084)

The comment mentions that

> If the block is persisted to the disk and stored at an executor running on the same host then first it is tried to be accessed using the local directories

Does this mean executor can access each other's object on disk if they share the same host?